# flash AS3 - Parameter child must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

getting error

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter
>   child must be non-null.   at
>   flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
>     at
>   fl.controls::ProgressBar/drawTrack()
>     at fl.controls::ProgressBar/draw()
>     at
>   fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()

within cs5, any ideas. thanks. The animation imports fine, but I am getting that error without the progress bar being shown.

```
import fl.controls.ProgressBar;
var swfRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("animation2.swf"); //load animation file
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var progressBarr:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
progressBarr.source = swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo;
progressBarr.x = 27;
progressBarr.y = 155;

loadMovie();

function loadMovie():void{
    addChild(progressBarr);
    swfLoader.load(swfRequest);
}

swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded, false, 0, true); //when loaded call swfLoaded
//swfLoader.load(swfRequest);
//
function swfLoaded(event:Event):void{
     swfMC.addChild(swfLoader); //add animation to swfMC movie clip
     removeChild(progressBarr);
}

stop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

giving no errors to me, in CS5, though one thing that you can check is, drag a progress bar component from the component window, save and run your file, then delete the instance. after that your code should do just fine.

also you can comment this line as:

```
var progressBarr:ProgressBar = new ProgressBar();
//progressBarr.source = swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo;
progressBarr.x = 27;
progressBarr.y = 155;
```

check fla here:

http://ashwani.50webs.com/test.fla

Comment: Alternatively, just drag it directly into the library, and then you won't need the extra step of deleting it. As long as you're using the class in code somewhere, then the class association with the symbol is enough to ensure the symbol and skins get included.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling

```
progressBarr.source = swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo;
```

after you intialized the loader?  You may need to wait until that has been instantiated before assigning anything to its contentLoaderInfo.  So, remove it up at the top and add it below the swfLoader.load call:

```
swfLoader.load(swfRequest);
progressBarr.source = swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo;
```